# Splitting an arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, split

Below is a code snippet to extract a part of arraylist. My arraylist `full` contains around 3000 lines with 193 digits separated by spaces in each line.
Now I want to split my arraylist to get the first 48 digits in each line, ie my final "ocr" arraylist should contain 3000 lines with 48 digits separated by space in each line.

Here, when I try copying the temp to ocr, and then print `ocr`, I am getting the entire arraylist instead of a sublist. What is wrong in this code?

```
void extractData(){

    ArrayList<points> test1 = new ArrayList<points>();
    points temp = new points();

    for (points p : full){
        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++){
            temp.x[i] = p.x[i];
        }
        ocr.add(temp);

    }
    for (points pp : ocr)
        System.out.println(pp);     
}
```

Comment: You're adding the same single `temp` object to `ocr` multiple times because you create it outside the loop. That's probably part of your problem, although I can't tell if it's your whole problem since you don't show enough context.

Comment: Also, please respect the Java naming conventions to make your code readable. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your temporary "temp" variable is reused in every iteration. Move the declaration inside the outer loop to fix it.

```
void extractData()
{

    List<points> test1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (points p : full)
    {
        points temp = new points();
        for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
        {
            temp.x[i] = p.x[i];
        }
        ocr.add(temp);

    }
    for (points pp : ocr)
    {
        System.out.println(pp);
    }
}
```

Please also note the Java naming conventions mentioned in the comments.